# jQuery.Mobile Styling Not Applied to Hot Towel Views

Tags: jquery-mobile, hottowel

In a [hot towel](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) app, a `<ul>` list is styling correctly within index.cshtml, but not in any of the hot towel views:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new MVC app using the hot towel template
- Add the nuget packages for hot towel and jQuery.Mobile
- Add jQuery.Mobile to the js and css bundles
- Put the `<ul>` section (below) in index.cshtml (in Views\HotTowel)
- Also put the `<ul>` section (below) in home.html (in App\views)

This is the HTML that goes in index.cshtml and home.html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
</ul>
```

Why is the list styling correctly in index.cshtml but not home.html? What do I need to do to also get the list to style correctly in home.html?